# How to put a input-text on the end of the Nav-bar?

Tags: html, css

```css
nav {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 200px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 my-1 divSearch">
      <form>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Search">
          <button type="submit">
            <img>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to place the `input` on the right side (at the end) of the `nav`. How can I do it?

I tried to put a  `float: right;`, `justify-content: flex-end;` and `align-content: flex-end`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Wrap the div `.divSearch` with `li` and add  `margin-left: auto;`
Also change `inline-flex` to `flex` for the `ul`

```css
nav {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 200px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.input-parent {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li class="input-parent">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 my-1 divSearch">
        <form>
          <div>
            <input placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit">
                      <img>
                  </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text], .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Input Field in Navbar</h2>
  <p>Navigation bar with a search box and a submit button inside of it.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have documented the changes in the CSS code

```css
nav {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 200px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex; /* Instead of inline-flex */
  list-style: none;
}

.divSearch {
  margin-left: auto; /* Pushes it to the right */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 my-1 divSearch">
      <form>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Search">
          <button type="submit">
            <img>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```